# What can I use instead of gets() in this case

Tags: c

```
printf("\nWhich minute to query?");
gets(query);
val = strcmp (query, out);

return 0;
```

I tried to use gets and it did not compile and it had a runtime error. What can I substitute to make it compile.

Comment: `fgets` is a safer, non-deprecated option.

Comment: `it did not compile and it had a runtime error` What? You can't have both.

Comment: Yes, [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: _It did not compile_: please show the error log.

Comment: there is already a query instance variable declared stack overflow just would'nt let me post entire code

Comment: what is an example of fgets thank you fred!

Comment: @Timothy: Click the link.

Comment: @Timothy google _c fgets_, and you should find what you need

Comment: 1. Throw away anything that tells you to use `gets` and read a modern book: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714). 2. Learn how to research before asking and learn how to read documentation. Read [ask] and [tour] to know how this site works. You don't post the whole code here but a [mcve]

Comment: @phuclv The very first book on that list teaches you to use `gets`... It's not a list of _recommended_ books, it's a list of _existing_ books (and other things) of diverse quality.

Comment: @Lundin that's why I said *modern*. There are good old books but it's not for everyone

Comment: A corner problem with `fgets()` over `gets()` is that `fgets()` requires a 1 byte larger buffer to cope with the same size maximal input as `gets()` does not need space for the `'\n'`, `fgets()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `fgets`:

```
char query[50];

printf("\nWhich minute to query?");
fgets(query,sizeof query,stdin);
val = strcmp (query, out);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example of `fgets()`, from my [read_stdin_fgets_string_and_arrow_keys.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/read_stdin_fgets_string_and_arrow_keys.c#L40-L46) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```c
    printf("Press any key followed by Enter, or just Enter alone, to continue: ");
    char buf[1024];
    char* retval = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    if (retval == NULL)
    {
        printf("fgets() failed!\n");
    }
    // `buf` now contains the contents of what you typed in
```